# Is there a way to use the timestamp function to draw a vertical line when the value no longer equals zero?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I'm trying to use the timestamp function to draw a vertical line when the value of my function no longer equals 0 using axvline. I have a function that varies from 0 to 1 named XV_tag, and I am trying to use axvline to draw a vertical line at the timestamp_x at the moment that XV_tag no longer equals 0.

Tried the following:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

#Find durations
start_i = 0
end_i = 1

# Conditions to be met variables
done_XV_loop = 0

while end_i < product_and_step_select_data.shape[0]:
    
    if (product_and_step_select_data["timestamp_x"][end_i] - product_and_step_select_data["timestamp_x"][start_i]).seconds > 60 or end_i == product_and_step_select_data.shape[0] - 1:
        
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69,8.27))
        plt.plot(product_and_step_select_data['timestamp_x'][start:end_i-1], product_and_step_select_data[XV_tag][start:end_i-1])
        
        
        if XV_tag != 0:
            plt.axvline(x = product_and_step_select_data['timestamp_x'][end_i-1], color = 'r', label = 'axvline - full height')
                
        else:
            plt.axvline(x = product_and_step_select_data['timestamp_x'][done_XV_loop], color = 'r', label = 'axvline - full height') 
        plt.show()

        
                
    start_i = end_i
    end_i = end_i + 1
```

Comment: What is the "timestamp function"? Python cannot draw lines by itself. Are you talking about some plotting library? You have not told us which one.

Comment: I'm using datetime to get the timestamp and matplotlib to plot the axvline. Sorry, I've only been learning Python a couple of weeks so I'm still pretty new!

Comment: Okay. And what is the particular problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: It is displaying the vertical line at the beginning of the function, not where the function changes from 0 to not 0.

Comment: I've included a picture of my output plot to help.

Comment: So your question is how to determine the correct `x`.

Comment: Yes, exactly...